# Selenium HTML Runner: port already in use

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am using selenium html runner to run the selenise scripts.

```
java -jar selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar -htmlSuite *firefox "https://www.google.com/" "D://file.html" "D://r.html"
```

While running for any browser I am getting this error stack:

```
Jan 09, 2017 4:14:47 PM org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher mainInt
WARNING: Test of browser failed: *firefox
java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.determineSuiteUrl(HTMLLauncher.java:180)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.runHTMLSuite(HTMLLauncher.java:108)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.mainInt(HTMLLauncher.java:245)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.main(HTMLLauncher.java:273)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.pollPort(PortProber.java:154)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.pollPort(PortProber.java:137)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.determineSuiteUrl(HTMLLauncher.java:174)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
        at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:644)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.pollPort(PortProber.java:146)
        ... 5 more
```

I am using html runner 3, firefox 50, geckodriver 0.11

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a socket binding exception,I think the default port is taken and some other process is running over it.

you can check that using:

```
netstat -a
```

Have you tried changing the port number?

just append -port 7272 (or any other port number for that matter)

Try:

```
java -jar selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar -htmlSuite *firefox "https://www.google.com/" "D://file.html" "D://r.html" -port 7272
```